# "When" + Infinitive (without "to")

Tags: grammaticality

Is such phrase like *"when make a call"* correct?

I wonder whether I can make a subjectless clause for describing the condition to perform some action. For example:

> To make a call, use a softphone application installed on the tablet,
>   that is in the conference hall.

I couldn't find any grammar rule describing such a case. Please, assist me in this question.

Comment: The punctuation convention is not to use a comma when the *that*-clause specifies the antecedent noun.  *the tablet that is in the conference hall*, that is, the tablet there, not some other tablet. The clause could be shortened to *...the tablet in the conference hall*.

Comment: Does it really sound okay "application installed on the tablet in the conference hall"? For me it sounds a little bit ambiguous.

Comment: I agree that the sentence as a whole is a little ambiguous in its choice of ***a** softphone application* followed by ***the** tablet...in the conference hall*. It suggests there are multiple such softphone applications installed on it. I'd expect **the** in both places.  But what ambiguity is added by using **in the conference hall** instead of **that is in the conference hall**?

Comment: Because it separates the "application installed" part from the "in the conference hall" part, I think.

Comment: I'd have to disagree. I don't see any ambiguity with *the tablet in the conference room* versus *the tablet that is in the conference room*.  But I would change **a** to **the**:  *... the softphone app...* unless you do mean to imply that there are several to choose from.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you.
But can I ask also what do you think of *"when make a call"* phrase? Do you agree that is would be right to put "make" into a gerund form to make *"when making a call"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"when make a call"- This Phrase is wrong.
You can write it like "When you make a call" or "When making a call"- I think this would be the correct way of writing that sentence.